Vercel domains - only the branch link loads the data
I was expecting to see my charts deployed on a random domain provided by vercel. It happens that this [https://macro-bi-madoption.vercel.app/] and the following links (except by the branch link which is the middle one in the picture below) are not loading the data properly:


macro-bi-madoption-miguelg97s-projects.vercel.app
macro-bi-madoption-git-main-miguelg97s-projects.vercel.app
macro-bi-madoption-kwq3ldwzp-miguelg97s-projects.vercel.app

This is what happens in most of the links:
image

However, when using the branch link domain, the data loads properly:

The data is coming from a excel file stored in the public folder by the way:

and I'm reading it using the following code (with help of xlsx package):
const res = await fetch(
  "/assets/files/BIMei Macro Adoption Study.xlsx"
);
if (res.ok) {
  const file = await res.arrayBuffer();
  const workbook = read(file);
  console.log(workbook);
  return workbook;
}

